# Flickr API - photos_public how to get more than 19 photos

Tags: json, flickr

An example api call is:
`https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=dog&tagmode=any&format=json`

Which only returns 20 images. Is there a way to get the next 20 images, or load more images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's API page doesn't say anything: https://www.flickr.com/services/feeds/docs/photos_public/

But I found another query to work with:

> https://api.flickr.com/services/rest?sort=relevance&parse_tags=1&content_type=7&extras=can_comment%2Ccount_comments%2Ccount_faves%2Cdescription%2Cisfavorite%2Clicense%2Cmedia%2Cneeds_interstitial%2Cowner_name%2Cpath_alias%2Crealname%2Crotation%2Curl_c%2Curl_l%2Curl_m%2Curl_n%2Curl_q%2Curl_s%2Curl_sq%2Curl_t%2Curl_z%2Cis_marketplace_licensable&per_page=50&page=1&lang=en-US&text=dog&viewerNSID=&method=flickr.photos.search&csrf=&api_key=fb4c82e7cd32fc74eb349aa61fc1b1aa&format=json&hermes=1&hermesClient=1&reqId=f866abd5&nojsoncallback=1

This one has all you need, including tag (*text* param), *page* and *per_page*.
I think you should to sing up your app [here](https://www.flickr.com/services/apps/create/) and you gonna to receive your own *api_key*.

Comment: Thanks very much George, I missed this!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There is the parameter &per_page= [number of photos].
Try https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=dog&tagmode=any&per_page=40&format=json